# What does half a pixel mean in the font-size CSS property?

Tags: html, font-size, pixel, css

I'm currently working on a website redesign and I'm receiving a list with the required changes from an agency.

The header menu of the site currently has the following styles:

```
line-height: 1em;
font-size: 11px;
```

In one of the documents I have received there's a change request that requires me to change those styles to:

```
line-height: 1.2em;
font-size: 11.5px;
```

I know that the EMs are OK with the decimal values but what does half a pixel mean in the font size? I have tried to change the font size using the inspector from *12* to *11.5* and to *11* and the change from *11* to *11.5* is visible but the one from *11.5* to *12* it moves just a little (I thins only the spacing changes a little, but it is set to *1em* on all 3 examples). You can check the screen-shots below:
[image]

So what does that half a pixel mean in the context of a web-page? Is this cross-browser and what does that *.5* pixel do to the font-size?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think there is a difference. You forgot about the Zoom level of the page.

Example :

```
<p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; border : 1px red solid;">
aAa
</p>
<p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11.8px; border : 1px red solid;">
aAa
</p>
<p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11.5px; border : 1px red solid;">
aAa
</p>
<p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11.2px; border : 1px red solid;">
aAa
</p>
<p style="display: inline-block; font-size: 11px; border : 1px red solid;">
aAa
</p>
```

If we zoom to 500%, we can see there is a difference:

[image: Zoom levels]

I think your browser has to round it because half pixels (real pixels) don't exist.

Zoom 100% :

Round(12 * 1.00) = 12

Round(11.5 * 1.00) = 12

Zoom 500% :

Round(12 * 5.00) = 60

Round(11.5 * 5.00) = 58

Answer (score 5):

The `font-size` property is used as a parameter when the browser draws characters, so it affects the size of glyphs. But when glyphs are rasterized to bitmaps, the effect of, say, increasing `font-size` by `0.5px` may vanish. Browsers may perform rasterization in different ways. Moreover, they may or may not use subpixel rendering, and in different ways.

If `line-height` has been set to `1em` and `font-size` is increased from `11.5px` to `12px`, then the height of the line box may remain the same or be increased by one pixel, depending on the rounding applied by a browser.