# Google Font size 10.5 px (.5) the correct way and multibrowser support

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using Google font Open Sans and if I set the font to font-size 11px it looks big for the text I need and if I set it to 10px it looks small so I tested just for fun and set it to 10.5px and it works on Chrome tested 10,5px with , and it does not work.

Is this correct that we can set values of font size to example:

10.1px or 10.2px or 10.3px or 10.5px ? or is that incorrect or new css or beta something?

I really would like it to work like 10.5px because is exactly the font-size I need but reading and reading I find nothing about it.

If this works is it supported by all browsers and cellphones ?

Comment: Useful article:
[What does half a pixel mean in the font-size CSS property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830473/what-does-half-a-pixel-mean-in-the-font-size-css-property)

Comment: Thanks m8 but the answer in this topic is very poor, it does not explain why it is working and is 1 year old while CSS and Browsers changes and updates everyday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the answer is that no, it is not a good approach if you want to make sure that your font renders precisely in a cross-browser fashion.  There is no such thing as a half-pixel when it comes to rendering the font, so you leave yourself open to different browser-applied rounding effects which could differ from browser to browser and between client devices, which have different resolutions and pixel densities.

Comment: Good answer Mike. Now what do you reccomend me to do? Maybe PT or EM ? to get the 10.5 px ?

Comment: @Cardinale Well `em` and `rem` in essence have the same issue in that there will ALWAYS be some browser rounding.  Both `em` and `rem` apply multipier to the inherited font size (`em` is based on parent font-size, `rem` is based on "root" - html element - font-size).  So say you have an inherited font-size of 10px and you apply `em` or `rem` of 1.15.  This would still multiply to 11.5 px.  The purported benefit you get from `em` or `rem` is that at least your fonts scale with each other in older browser that don't have good support for text size changing when using "zoom" (*cough* IE *cough*).

Comment: @Cardinale I generally prefer px-based layouts when targetting modern browsers as you at least don't have issue with compounding of `em` such that you get unpredictable calculated font sizes when the are multiple `em` specifications in the inheritance chain.  `rem` helps solve this (as you only inherit from root element), but doesn't yet have full browser support.

Comment: PX was the best solution. I just shorted the space between letters words and lines making it really beautiful

Answer (score 0):

Convert your font size to a scalable unit like `em` or `rem`, and you can get what you are looking for.

By default, `1rem = 16px`. so `10.5px = 0.65625rem`.

The added benefit is accessibility.  Some users may increase their default font size.  Your text will scale accordingly if you use `em` or `rem` units.  Pixel sizes won't.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Does EM works on all browsers even on Android? What is the difference between EM and REM?

Comment: EMs (traditional typographical term referring to the width of the letter "m") and REMs are similar, the main difference is that EMs are relative to the parent element, meaning that if you set a `p` to `1em` and `p span` to `1.1em`, the text in the `span` will be 10% larger than the rest of the text in the `p`. `REM` (Root EM) units are always relative to the root font size, that is the font size set for the HTML or BODY element of the document.  Support for EM is universal, and REM is also well supported in modern browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=rem)

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage instead, you won't get the same size on different displays/browsers, but you should get more control over the size of your text.

e.g:
`font-size: 98%;`

[This article](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) may help.