# Is "10.3px" is valid property value in css

Tags: html, css

Is "10.3px"  is valid property value in css?
Can i apply value like this in pixels?
Eg:

```
p{
letter-spacing:10.233px;
}
```

Comment: check it sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218556/google-font-size-10-5-px-5-the-correct-way-and-multibrowser-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need fine-grained control, sizing fonts in pixel values (px) is an excellent choice (it's my favorite). **On a computer screen, it doesn't get any more accurate than a single pixel**. With sizing fonts in pixels, you are literally telling browsers to render the letters exactly that number of pixels in height:

Comment: so syntaxicaly there is no problem of using this kind of values right?

Answer (score 2):

Pixel is the indivisible unit for display. So browser can't "draw" `.3 px`. This will lead to different render of font in different browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can use it for percentage but not for pixel.

e.g.

```
p{
letter-spacing:3.5%;
}
```

In case of pixel. the values are truncated. So 10px, 10.233px, 10.9 px will show same letter spacing...