# How do float font-size values on CSS render among browsers?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

The CSS `em` unit is great, but there are things that always annoyed me, probably because I don't understand them completely.

Fonts don't render equally right at every size, and especially bad at inexact values. That is why, if you want to give using `em` exact pixel values to fonts, you have to do things like (assuming you didn't change the 16px font size of the body):

```
font-size: 0.875em; /* 14px */
font-size: 1.25em; /* 18px */
```

Maybe you just wanted to increase the size a little, but then realised that `0.9em` = `14.4px`, and then you got scared your font may look blurry! In any case, if you give a paragraph a `font-size` of `1.25em` (`18px`), and then, change the body size from 16px to 14px, then the paragraph would be `17.5px`. Blurry again!

Assuming we are working on common 1x ration screens like desktop ones, how would, for example, a `11.5px` font render? I've printed them on a test HTML file and they seem to look exactly like a `12px` font.

**Is this the recommended behaviour among all browsers? And what about sizes like padding and margin that may be determined by font-size when using ems? Do they get rounded up as well?**

I made a comparison between the renderings on 3 mayor browsers. Here it is:

[image]

I scaled it up (200%) a little, so that it is easier to see the details. At the top, you can see how the same text renders at 14px (left) and 14.4px (right). Below, I overlayed them on photoshop using Difference blendmode to see if there is any difference at all. As you can see, Chrome rounds the font-size, and renders it at the same size, meanwhile, the height of the box, is different.  Firefox has same height but the font renders slightly different on the x axis, while the height of the font seems equal. IE result is kind of a mix. In any case, I'm really surprised because the 14.4px font doesn't seem to be blured at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a simple question and does not apply "exactly" to the browser.
It's more a question about the whole rendering systems used and about "continuous spaces vs. discrete spaces" or "draw a curve using square boxes".

Some texts that could help to have a better understanding about the question:

(Try results from google searchs "font rendering discrete space","sub-pixel font rendering", or "font hinting")

http://jcgt.org/published/0002/01/04/paper.pdf
http://www.cutebugs.net/files/curve/fabris97antialiasing.pdf
http://lspwww.epfl.ch/publications/typography/frsa.pdf
https://www.grc.com/ctwho.htm

A "right" behaviour is difficult to define here, and so a "default behaviour" becomes almost impossible. It's a mathematical question about space and human perception more than about browsers behavior or CSS.

...anyway the discribed behaviour about "moving 1 pixel" is related to the font hinting technique the browser or system uses.

Comment: This is a lot of helpful information and you look read, but in the end, it is not a clear answer, it is just "it depends". I know it is hard but could you extract a general rule for safe use in mose cases? Do you think it is safe using subpixel font sizes or not?

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but there is no real answer to the question. The rendering of the font (position and size) depends not only on the browser, but also on the O.S., the graphic system configuration, the pixel density, the media... The only rule of thumb I trust is: 0.875 rem or smaller is dangerous for legibility and sizing or positioning using decimal (CSS) pixels only works well in printing media (hight resolution or "pixel ratio": 1css pixel = many media pixels). A media pixel is just a single pixel and can't be divided.

Answer (score 1):

> But is this the recommended behavior among all browsers?

Here is what I found on [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths)

> The reference pixel
>   is the visual angle of one pixel on a device with a pixel density of 96dpi and a distance from the reader of an arm’s length. For a nominal arm’s length of 28 inches, the visual angle is therefore about 0.0213 degrees. For reading at arm’s length, 1px thus corresponds to about 0.26 mm (1/96 inch).

So `1px` does not necessarily correspond the 1 pixel on the screen, see image below:

So even though you could calculate based on `0.25px` (using the pixel value above), to move elements by 1 literal screen pixel, it is not done.

> And what about sizes like padding and margin that may be determined by font-size when using ems? Do they get rounded up as well?

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22830473/5620297), it may be of use. Basically the values **are rounded**. The reason your `11.5px` looked the same as `12px` was because it was rounded up. `11.4px` would look just like `11px`

Also look at [this website](http://atirip.com/2013/09/22/yes-we-can-do-fraction-of-a-pixel/), it provides some interesting behavior on how this works.

See the Code Snippet below an example. See how the div only gets moved down by one pixel on `translateY(0.5px)`, this proves the browser rounds the value:

```css
.box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  display: inline-block;
}
#cont {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.1px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.2px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.3px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.4px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.5px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.6px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.7px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.8px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(0.9px)"></div>
  <div class="box" style="transform: translateY(1.0px)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my case I don't see a jump from 0.5px, I see one line of horizontal pixels fading more and more untill they disappear

Comment: What browser are you using. I tested this on Firefox 45 and 47?

Answer (score -1):

This is not a really tought question you need to define css in a hierarchical manner:

```
.box {
    font-size: 1em; /* size according to your*/
}
```

This is your `div` value suppose you have another heading tag in your box content:

```
.box h2 {
    font-size:14px;
}
```