# How to Create a Consistently Styled Pipe Separated List with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to create an inline list with pipe separators between list items using CSS. I've implemented the following CSS code:

```
.list .list--pipe {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .list__item {
        padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    }

    .list__item::before {
        height: 22px;
        right: 9px;
        top: 2px;
        width: 1.5px;
    }

    .list__item:last-child::before {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

However, I'm encountering an issue where the width of the pipe separators seems to vary depending on the resolution. I've set a fixed width for the `::before` pseudo-element, but it still appears inconsistent across resolutions. Sometimes when I zoom in or out, the pipes seem like they have the same `1.5px` width, but often it seems to have differing widths.

Here's a picture of my problem:

[image: Different separator line sizes]

What steps can I take to ensure that the pipe separators have a consistent width across different resolutions? Is there a more reliable approach to achieve this styling? I am expecting the pipe separators to have the same width on all screen sizes. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is the half a pixel, these get rounded up/down by the browser. Pick a whole number (I'd suggest 2px).

Comment: I tried it with different widths, It unfortunately does the same with 2px width lines.

Comment: Your HTML is missing - Please add enough code to create a [mre]

Comment: _Sometimes when I zoom in or out_ - I'm going to say this is still a subpixel rendering issue. Regardless if you set a specific width, when you zoom in or out, it's no longer just `1.5px` - the browser needs to interpret what `110%`, `125%`, etc. And each browser is going to determine the width a bit differently. I would strongly recommend not worrying about this.

Comment: Highly relevant if not a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830473/what-does-half-a-pixel-mean-in-the-font-size-css-property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does half a pixel mean in the font-size CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830473/what-does-half-a-pixel-mean-in-the-font-size-css-property)